# Computed properties from SQL in Entity Framework DB first

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, calculated-columns

I have an existing database table that is called connectors.
I am trying build a .net application that uses Entity Framework 6.
At one point I am trying to extract a list of connectors using the EF. But the problem is that in my query I created a computed column.

the entity class is something like this :

```
namespace ActionService.Models
{
    public partial class Connector
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public int version { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and a partial class like this :

```
 namespace ActionService.Models
 {
     public partial class Connector
     {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public bool hasDraft 
     }
 }
```

My code to extract the content is something like this:

```
 var models = db.Connectors.SqlQuery(" SELECT *,IIF(status=1, 'True', 'False') as 'hasDraft'  From  [Connectors] c  " +
              "WHERE c.[version] = (Select Max([version]) from [Connectors] c2 where c2.number = c.number)").ToList();
```

and the sql query returns a table like this :

```
id  name    description             type    number  version status  hasDraft
5   new     this is new desc wesee  SQL     1       5       1       True
```

As we can see the hasDraft is a computed column that is generated through the query has value of True.

but in my var models object (only 1 record right now) the hasDraft value is false; Even though I monitored the query with sql profiler and made sure it returns true on the hasDraft field. However all other field values are been passed through correctly. The hasDraft field seem to be the only field that has its value failed to be passed through. how would I make the computed column values get through?